# depoly user-storage-jpa keycloak quike start?

Tags: keycloak, external-dependencies

recently I am trying to implement a custom user storage provider for keycloak in order to integrate keycloak with external database, therefore I cloned the keycloak quick start and used the user-storage-jpa, first of all I copied the conf/quarkus.propeties file to the conf directory of keycloak distribution with the initial properties like this

```
quarkus.datasource.user-store.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.user-store.username=sa
quarkus.datasource.user-store.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgres:mem:user-store;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

, then apply "mvn clean install " to generate the jar file , after that copied the jar to provider directory, and start the keycloak using  " sh  kc.sh start-dev", and here where I gt the following error:

> > 2023-05-21 13:40:04,283 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main)
> > Hostname settings: Base URL: , Hostname: , Strict
> > HTTPS: false, Path: , Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL:
> > , Admin: , Port: -1, Proxied: false 2023-05-21
> > 13:40:08,196 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main)
> > Datasource  enables XA but transaction recovery is not
> > enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting
> > quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may
> > be lost if the application is terminated abruptly 2023-05-21
> > 13:40:08,632 WARN
> > [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator]
> > (JPA Startup Thread: user-store) HHH000181: No appropriate connection
> > provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying
> > connections 2023-05-21 13:40:08,637 WARN
> > [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA
> > Startup Thread: user-store) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to
> > query metadata: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The
> > application must supply JDBC connections  at
> > org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> > at
> > org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:272)
> > at
> > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.recording.PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.buildSessionFactoryOptionsBuilder(PrevalidatedQuarkusMetadata.java:68)
> > at
> > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:72)
> > at
> > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:72)
> > at
> > javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
> > at
> > javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
> > at
> > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:165)
> > at
> > io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:66)
> > at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
>
> 2023-05-21 13:40:12,214 INFO  [org.infinispan.SERVER]
> (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN005054: Native IOUring transport not
> available, using NIO instead: io.netty.incubator.channel.uring.IOUring
> 2023-05-21 13:40:12,407 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE]
> (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and
> planned for removal 2023-05-21 13:40:12,490 WARN
> [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to
> persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
> 2023-05-21 13:40:12,585 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER]
> (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller
> 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller' 2023-05-21
> 13:40:13,562 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init)
> ISPN000088: Unable to use any JGroups configuration mechanisms
> provided in properties {}. Using default JGroups configuration!
> 2023-05-21 13:40:13,888 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER]
> (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel `ISPN`
> 2023-05-21 13:40:13,948 INFO  [org.jgroups.JChannel]
> (keycloak-cache-init) local_addr:
> c484dc46-4679-4ad0-bb51-9d4b0fc4131b, name:
> kaisios-Inspiron-3521-32921 2023-05-21 13:40:13,956 WARN
> [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the send
> buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 1MB, but the OS only
> allocated 212.99KB 2023-05-21 13:40:13,957 WARN
> [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the
> receive buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 20MB, but the OS
> only allocated 212.99KB 2023-05-21 13:40:13,958 WARN
> [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the send
> buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 1MB, but the OS only
> allocated 212.99KB 2023-05-21 13:40:13,959 WARN
> [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the
> receive buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 25MB, but the OS
> only allocated 212.99KB 2023-05-21 13:40:13,978 INFO
> [org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK2] (keycloak-cache-init) server
> listening on *.37035 2023-05-21 13:40:15,992 INFO
> [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init)
> kaisios-Inspiron-3521-32921: no members discovered after 2010 ms:
> creating cluster as coordinator 2023-05-21 13:40:16,040 INFO
> [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000094: Received
> new cluster view for channel ISPN: [kaisios-Inspiron-3521-32921|0] (1)
> [kaisios-Inspiron-3521-32921] 2023-05-21 13:40:16,073 INFO
> [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000079: Channel
> `ISPN` local address is `kaisios-Inspiron-3521-32921`, physical
> addresses are `[172.22.0.1:52571]` 2023-05-21 13:40:17,316 INFO
> [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (main) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups
> channel `ISPN` ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
> ERROR: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> user-store] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory ERROR:
> [PersistenceUnit: user-store] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> ERROR: The application must supply JDBC connections For more details
> run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use
> '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.

therefore I changed the propertes to use a postgres database with the following prop:

```
quarkus.datasource.user-store.db-kind=postgres
quarkus.datasource.user-store.username=test
quarkus.datasource.user-store.password=test
quarkus.datasource.user-store.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgres:mem:user-store;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

unfortunately, the same error has raised,
any help of what I am missing ... thanks in advance.